# SilverStripe Form Redirecting Error

Tags: silverstripe

If I click the submit button to send data from my `SilverStripe` form to the database (`xampp, mysql`), it doesn't redirect me back to the form page. Instead it redirects to `{BaseUrl}name_of_controller/name_of_form` -> in my case: `localhost/pmtool/DeveloperController/NewTaskMask`. I have searched for hours for the solution of this problem, but without any success.

Here's the code of the file, in which the form and the action is defined. 
In another html-file the form will be called through `$NewTaskMask`. By the URL `localhost/pmtool/developer/newtask` the function `renderNewTaskForm` will be called, the template with `$NewTaskMask` will be rendered.

All fields such as Title, Description, etc do exist in the database.

```
class DeveloperController extends ContentController {

    private static $allowed_actions = array('NewTaskMask','renderNewTaskForm');

    private static $url_handlers = array(
        'newtask' => 'renderNewTaskForm'
    );

    public function renderNewTaskForm(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        return $this->renderWith('NewTaskForm');
    }

    public function NewTaskMask() {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create('Title','Title')
                ->setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter a task title ...'),
            TextareaField::create('Description','Description')
                ->setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'),
            DropdownField::create('Project','Project', Project::get()->map('ID','Title')),
            DropdownField::create('Developer','Developer', Developer::get()->map('ID','Title'))
        );

        $actions = new FieldList(FormAction::create('doCreateT','Task anlegen'));

        $requiredFields = new RequiredFields(array('Title'));

        return new Form($this, 'NewTaskMask', $fields, $actions, $requiredFields);
    }

    public function doCreateT($data, $form) {

        // Creating a new task record
        $nT = new Task();

        $nT->Title = $data['Title'];
        $nT->Description = $data['Description'];
        $nT->Project = $data['ProjectID'];
        $nT->Developer = $data['DeveloperID'];
        $nT->write();

        // Create a nice msg for our users
        $form->sessionMessage('Task angelegt!','good');

        // Redirect back to the form page
        return $this->redirectBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with routing. I assume you've set up the `developer` route to hit `DveloperController`. Doing the same I could reproduce your error.

I tried explicitly adding another route for `DeveloperController` to hit the `DeveloperController` controller, because it wasn't redirecting properly. It's a pretty weird and magic fix and to be honest I'm not sure why it works, but it solved it:

```yml
---
Name: mysiteroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'developer//$Action/$ID/$Name': 'DeveloperController'
    'DeveloperController//$Action/$ID/$Name': 'DeveloperController'
```

Update the routes to correspond with your setup and don't forget to run `?flush` afterwards.

Maybe someone with more insight can explain what's going on.

Comment: thx Janne for your answer, but:
it redirects now back, okay good, but the action of the form ("doCreateT") won't be called. You can check this when you put some echo ("hello"); commands in the action. Also no database entry has been created, because of the problem that the action won't be reached

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It works for me running [this code](https://gist.github.com/janneklouman/80840d1c142087325d1f1e5476814482).

Comment: now it works! your solution is right. thank you very much!
But I have another problem, see the next answer

Answer (score 0):

I want to render the page "localhost/pmtool/developer/$ID" with a template.
So I added **'$ID!' => 'index'** to the url_handlers. But now it's the same problem as in the beginning. Do I have to add another route for this problem or has the line **'$ID!' => 'index'** a bug?

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'newtask' => 'renderNewTaskForm',
    '$ID!' => 'index'
);

public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        return $this->renderWith('DeveloperTemplate');
}
```

Comment: You've already defined the route `developer//$Action/$ID/$Name` that can't coexist with `developer//$ID!`. However all requests will hit the index task by default so you should be able to just omit `'$ID!$ => 'index'`, and then in the index function you can grab the parameters by doing `$request->param('ID')`.

Comment: I haven't seen your answer til now. The issue is fixed. Created a new controller that handles the new route 'localhost/pmtool/developer/projects/$ID'. Now the index-function will be handled by the new controller. But thx for your answer! I think your solution would have been a quicker and better solution :D